# Is it possible to have an attribute on an XML closing tag?

Tags: xml

Is there any attribute that can be set on closing xml tag?
For instance :

```
</clt info="xxxx">
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker : For deeply indented xml structure, it would be nice to add some human readable info to tell which level this tag is closing. I don't know if we have to bother God for this though.

Comment: Use a comment immediately after the end tag for that.

Comment: @Quentin : I've done that but VS put automatically comment on a new line. This isn't much clearer...

Comment: Use a non-silly XML editor.

Comment: @bmargulies You should have said "Use a Mac" instead.

Comment: That would have been excessive. There are plenty of XML editors that run on Windows ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML-closing tags are defined as tags that cannot have attributes.

Why would you do something like this anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create another tag just inside the last one ad set that to something like `closing-TAG_NAME`?

```
<xml>
  <name>Mike</name>
  <age>25</age>
  ...
  <close>closing-Mike</close>
</xml>
```

It would never have to be displayed, just for the dev.